# Transformation function to be applied on every row in data frame

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas

I load a JSON file into a dataframe and want to apply one function on every single row. I will use the existing column "item_name" and do some logical checks and add a new column in the dataframe. But this doesn't work actually and throwing some error.

```
 def load_data(data_file):
    with open(data_file, 'r', encoding='utf8') as d:
       data = json.load(d)
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
    df = df_gt.apply(name_list, axis=1)

def name_list(df):
    for column in df[['item_name']]:
        names = []
        #processing ...
        names.append(value)
    df['names_list'] = names
    return(df)
```

Inside my second function, name_list, when I try to print df, I am getting error. Hence would like to know how to pass the entire dataframe as argument

Comment: Is there a question here? You don't _need_ to [show us](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) the contents of `data_file`, but if you want SO contributors to help you should let them copy-n-paste a subset of those rows. I don't know what "some error" means. I cannot reproduce that error, based on what you've shared so far.

Comment: S added my challenges

Comment: How to pass the entire dataframe as argument

Comment: Do you need `df = df_gt.pipe(name_list)` ?

Comment: `df.apply()` with `axis=1` iterates the df row by row and applies function to each row. If `name_list()` function can process each individual row, then you don't need to pass entire df. You need to show us sample dataframe and expected output.